# In Play Framework 1.2.x, how to use a render arg value in a path expression?

Tags: groovy, playframework-1.x

Let's say that I have a renderArg named `xyz`. In the groovy template, what's the syntax for using the value of the renderArg in a path expression?

For example:

```
href="@@{'/public/stylesheets/whatever/${xyz}.css'}"
```

The above fails with a template compilation error (which is what I expected, really). How can I use the value of the render arg inside the path string?

I'll also need to use the arg in other path expressions (not just for a css file reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it directly, but there is one workaround:

First you should have defined route to root of the application, for instance:

```
GET    /      Application.index
```

next you can use it in this way:

```
href="@@{Application.index}public/stylesheets/whatever/${xyz}.css"
```

If you repeat the structure above very often, then you can use custom tag, to do so:

1. add file `/app/views/tags/customlink.html`(**customlink** is name of the tag, you can use another one),
2. fill the content:

   @@{Application.index}public/stylesheet/whatever/${_key}.css
3. You can use it now in this way:

   href="#{customlink key:'xyz' /}"

More about custom tags you [can read here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/templates#tags)